# Can multiple nginx statements be on the same line in a config file?

Tags: nginx, configuration, docker, environment-variables, gettext

## The Problem

I'm creating a docker image which dynamically creates nginx config based on environment variables. I would like to minimise the number of environment variables required.

I have a config template file that looks something like this:

```
server {
...
  $ALLOW_DENY
...
}
```

And I'd like to configure the template like this

```sh
export ALLOW_DENY="allow 11.11.11.11; deny all;"
envsubst '\$ALLOW_DENY' < sites-available/site.template > sites-available/my-site
```

My problem is that I don't want to create multiple environment variables for each allow or deny statement (some configurations of this file might require none, where others might require 5 or 6) but I can't find a way to make `envsubst` accept newline characters, and I'm not sure if multiple nginx commands are allowed on a single line.

For reference, I'm going to be loading all my environment variables using `aws ssm` and I don't think it accepts multi-line environment variables like this:

```sh
export $ALLOW_DENY="  allow 11.11.11.11;
  deny all;"
```

## tl;dr

Is this valid?

```
server {
...
  allow 11.11.11.11; deny all;
...
}
```

Comment: You could have tested whether that worked in less time than it took you to write this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes.** Though I highly recommend making liberal use of whitespaces, line breaks and `include` statements to increase readability - ultimately **its up to you to skip line breaks where convenient** - nginx only treats line breaks special to be able to point out the line where configuration parser errors occurred.

nginx configuration files are nothing more than semicolon-separated directives in curly-brace-delimited blocks - line breaks are irrelevant other than being parsed similar to spaces and tabs:

> A simple directive consists of the name and parameters separated by
>   spaces and ends with a semicolon (;). A block directive has the same
>   structure as a simple directive, but instead of the semicolon it ends
>   with a set of additional instructions surrounded by braces ({ and }).

The only reason you do not want to too much of your configuration in a single line is readability - and comments are only possible on a line basis:

> The rest of a line after the # sign is considered a comment.

[Nginx Beginner’s Guide](https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html)

Comment: Thank you, very helpful